# Resolve multi module Maven dependency to classifier artifact only during package/assembly

Tags: maven

I have a multi-module Maven project that produces a build artifact `child-classifier.tar.gz` during the `package` phase. My CI build process **requires** running `mvn test-compile` before it runs `mvn deploy`.

For `maven-assembly-plugin` to include the artifact, it must be declared as a dependency in the `package.pom` project.

`mvn clean test-compile` fails dependency resolution, since `child-classifier.tar.gz` doesn't exist yet.

`mvn clean package` works, since the `child-classifier` artifact is built before the `package.pom` module is executed. But, as stated above, it is not an option on the CI server.

*(I am omitting the group and version details for simplicity)*

**Question:** How can I declare the dependency in `package.pom` to `child-classifier.tar.gz` that is only resolved during the `package.pom` `assembly` execution?

**Maven Module Layout**

```
parent.pom
  + child.pom
    - creates child.jar
    - creates child-classifier.tar.gz
  + package.pom
    + package-assembly.xml
      - unpacks child-classifer.tar.gz to /classifier dir
      - places child.jar in / dir
```

I have tried to [Include Module Binaries](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/multimodule/module-binary-inclusion-simple.html) by defining a `<moduleSet>` in the assembly descriptor and `<useAllReactorProjects>true</useAllReactorProjects>`, but the artifact inclusion filter for `child:tar.gz:classifier` is never triggered.

I have tried to [Exclude Dependencies from Dependency Analysis](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/exclude-dependencies-from-dependency-analysis.html), by configuring `<ignoredDependency>child:tar.gz:classifier</ignoredDependency>`, but the assembly artifact inclusion filter for `child:tar.gz:classifier` is never triggered.

**Workaround**

Declare a `<fileSet>` in the assembly descriptor and include the files that would normally make up the `child-classifier.tar.gz` file using a relative path to the `child` project.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to work around my problem by moving `maven-dependency-plugin` to the `prepare-package` phase within the `package.pom`.

*This may not be ideal, since it would be useful to resolve all other dependencies (including sibling modules, excluding the `classifier` artifact) for the `package.pom` during the standard `analyze`/`compile` phase.*

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>...</groupId>
  <artifactId>child</artifactId>
  <version>${project.version}</version>
  <type>tar.gz</type>
  <classifier>classifier</classifier>
</dependency>

<build>   
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>package-dependencies</id>
        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>analyze-only</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</build>
```